# Parse JSON with duplicate keys using custom Newtonsoft JSON converter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an invalid JSON, that I need to parse using Newtonsoft. The problem is that instead of using a proper array, the JSON contains duplicate properties for each entry in the array.

I've got some working code, but really not sure if this is the way to go or if there's an easier way?

The invalid JSON:

```
{
    "Quotes": {
        "Quote": {
            "Text": "Hi"
        },
        "Quote": {
            "Text": "Hello"
        }
    }
}
```

The object I'm trying to serialize into:

```
class MyTestObject
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NewtonsoftQuoteListConverter))]
    public IEnumerable<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}

class Quote
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The read method of the `JsonConverter`

```
public override IEnumerable<Quote> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IEnumerable<Quote> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var quotes = new List<Quote>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Path.Equals("quotes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            // This is the end of the Quotes block. We've parsed the entire object. Stop reading.
            break;
        }
        
        if (reader.Path.Equals("quotes.quote", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            // This is the start of a new Quote object. Parse it.
            quotes.Add(serializer.Deserialize<Quote>(reader));
        }
    }
    
    return quotes;
}
```

I only need reading of JSON with duplicate keys, not writing.

Comment: Do you need to write JSON with duplicate keys, or just read?

Comment: @dbc Just read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see a few problems with your converter:

1. Because you hardcode the path, your converter won't work when `MyTestObject` is embedded in some higher-level container.  In fact it will likely leave the reader positioned incorrectly.
2. Your converter doesn't correctly skip past comments.
3. Your converter doesn't populate the incoming `existingValue` when present, which is necessary when deserializing get-only collection properties.
4. You don't take the current [naming strategy](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySkipSpecifiedNames.htm) into account.
5. Your converter will not throw an exception or otherwise indicate an error when a truncated file is encountered.

As an alternative, you might take advantage of the fact that Json.NET will call the setter for a property multiple times when that property is encountered multiple times in the JSON, to accumulate the `"Quote"` property values with a set-only surrogate property in a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) like so:

```
class NewtonsoftQuoteListConverter : JsonConverter<IEnumerable<Quote>>
{
    class DTO
    {
        public ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; init; }
        public Quote Quote { set => Quotes.Add(value); }
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Quote> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IEnumerable<Quote> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var dto = new DTO { Quotes = existingValue is ICollection<Quote> l && !l.IsReadOnly ? l : new List<Quote>() }; // Reuse existing value if possible
        serializer.Populate(reader, dto); 
        return dto.Quotes;
    }
    
    public override bool CanWrite => true; // Replace with false if you don't need custom serialization.
    
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,  IEnumerable<Quote> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Handle naming strategies.
        var name = ((JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(DTO))).Properties.Where(p => p.UnderlyingName == nameof(DTO.Quote)).First().PropertyName;
    
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(name);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

By using a DTO, the current naming convention is taken into account.

If you don't need custom serialization, override [`CanWrite`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanWrite.htm) and return `false`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5AvyHa).

Comment: Haha, thanks! I had a hunch that my solution wasn't all that good... :D I can confirm that this works well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can not deserialize json to c# instance with a double properties since c# doesn't allow it. So you need to create alternative class without double properties and fix json accordingly. After this  you can deserialize without any problem.

You can fix json with several different ways, but this one looks the simpliest for me

```
var jsonOrig=" ... your json";

var json=jsonOrig.Replace("Quotes\":{","Quotes\":[{").Replace("}}}","}}]}");

var quotesRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuotesRoot>(json);

 List<QuoteItem> quotes=quotesRoot.Quotes;
```

result

```
{
  "Quotes": [
    {
      "Quote": {
        "Text": "Hi"
      }
    },
    {
      "Quote": {
        "Text": "Hello"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

classes

```
public partial class QuotesRoot
    {
        [JsonProperty("Quotes")]
        public List<QuoteItem> Quotes { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class QuoteItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("Quote")]
        public Quote Quote { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Quote
{
    [JsonProperty("Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```